# Dirichlet boundary conditions in generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: finite-element, pde, eigenvalues, eigensystem

Let us consider a problem of the form

$$(\mathcal{L} + k^2) u(\mathbf{x})=0\, ,\quad \forall \mathbf{x} \in \Omega$$

with Dirichlet boundary conditions

$$u(\mathbf{x}) = 0, \quad \forall \mathbf{x} \in \partial\Omega\, .$$

We discretize this problem using, for example, the finite element method, to obtain the following generalized eigenvalue problem

$$[K]\{U\} = k^2 [M]\{U\} \, .$$

To impose boundary conditions one can do one of the following:

1. Reduce the system by deleting rows/columns corresponding to boundary degrees of freedom in matrices $[K]$ and $[M]$.
2. Zero row/column values for the boundary degrees of freedom of both matrices $[K]$ and $[M]$, and fix the diagonal values in $[K]$ to any finite number. The problem with this approach is that the matrix $[M]$ loses its positive-definiteness (if it was) and eigensolvers do not like this.
3. Zero row/column values for the boundary degrees of freedom of both matrices $[K]$ and $[M]$, and fix the diagonal values in $[M]$ to any finite number.

For eigenvalue problems I have (almost) exclusively used 1, while I have used the other methods (or equivalent) for solving linear systems of equations.

#### Questions

- What is the most common method used for imposing Dirichlet boundary conditions?
- Is there any other method that I have not mentioned?

This question has been partially answered in [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/24848/9667).

Comment: Try Lagrange multipliers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u$ is described spectrally, then there are other methods as I mentioned in that old answer. If not, I am unsure of additional options for you. This is a well-known problem that often results in spurious eigenvalues, with plenty of literature to back it up (e.g. [see here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~complex/pubs/siam_spurious.pdf)). Most of it lies in the area of hydrodynamic stability, which might help guide your search, or at least assure yourself you are in good company.

From what I have seen, most people use approach 1. from your question if possible, though  I prefer approach 2 as it is more general. If you're keen on maintaining positive-definiteness of $M$, then you might be able to modify option 2. to accommodate this: instead of zero-ing all the boundary values/rows you care about, you can constrain those rows to be such that $M$ remains PD, then modify the associated row of $K$ to be whatever it needs to be to satisfy your boundary condition. I have some concern that this might only be possible in the spectral space, since in that case all of the DOFs of $u$ would be associated with the BC (and so you have more options to play around with).